# Can I use the iOS Enterprise program as a TestFlight alternative?

Tags: ios, coronasdk, enterprise, testflight

I am creating a mobile app using corona sdk, which seems to not be supported by apple's TestFlight since the release of iOS 8. Can I use the Enterprise program in as an alternative?

I need something to deploy apps to my beta testers - or users - yet they are not part of my company. Is that possible with enterprise? How would I approach this? I have searched through many documents but found no clear answer.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the enterprise program. The terms are very clear: distribute within a company only:

> Enroll in the Enterprise Program if you wish to distribute proprietary
>   iOS apps to employees within your company/organization.

From https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/enterprise/

Also, you will not benefit from the distribution infrastructure that Testflight offers.

With Testflight the users are notified that new versions are available and you can see who is running what version of your app.

With the enterprise program there is no such infrastructure out of the box.

Comment: Than what is meant by this: Opt-in enrollment.
Users can simply enroll in MDM within minutes on their personal device by initiating the installation of a configuration profile. And when no longer needed, users have the option to opt out of enrollment at any time by removing the profile from the device.

Comment: Can you add the reference to the quote? As it stands, it simply says the apps can be installed via MDM. Doesn't say anything about who is allowed to do that. The quote I have above is pretty final about who can install the app in the enterprise program IMO. If you have a quote that says users not affiliated with the company can use it, I'd like to see it. If you want to manage beta testers, TestFlight is better.

Comment: The quote is from one of the apple enterprise getting started guide I believe. Its one of apple's documents for sure.

Comment: And I just found out that http://lococat.com is using enterprise - and I was able to download it without any problem, even if I don't have any affiliation with them...

Comment: Well, I can do is to point again to the quote I found and posted in my answer. If you really want to be sure about it, you may want to post a question to Apple in your development account. Also, TestFlight will help you manage the distribution of your beta apps (it was meant for that). If you decide to go with the enterprise distribution you will have to find another way to distribute the apps.